# angular momentjs date issues

Tags: angularjs, date, momentjs

I am having a heck of a time trying to generate dates using moment.js inside of angular. I just want to create random dates and I don't have any clue as to how.

I've looked through http://momentjs.com/ but I don't know how to convert the js to the angular format.

Here is the link

http://jsfiddle.net/galnova/Pe2Zc/150/

If you look below you can see a snippet here.

Here is the snippet

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.constant("moment", moment);

app.controller("ctrl", function($scope, moment) {
    $scope.d = new Date();
    $scope.date = new moment();
    $scope.date2 = moment().add('days', 7); 
});
```

Here is the html

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

    {{ date }} <br/> <br/>

    {{ date2 }} <br/> <br/>

    {{d | date: 'MMM-dd-yyyy'}} <br/> <br/>

    {{d | date: 'MMM-dd-yyyy'}}

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working now, check this

https://jsbin.com/wohucud/edit?html,js,output

```
app.controller("ctrl", function($scope, moment) {
    $scope.getRandomDate = function(){
        var year = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 2015;
        var month = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12) ;
        var day = Math.floor(Math.random() * 31);
        return moment([year, month, day]).toDate();
   };
   $scope.date = $scope.getRandomDate(); 

});
```

And also give some credit to @Leandro

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! How did you figure it out!?

Comment: I thought that moment() object has methods like add(), subtract() so actually   it is not a date object while angular date filter works with date object so I changed getRandomDate() a bit to return pure date object...

Answer (score 2):

I have updated the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Pe2Zc/152/

```
$scope.getRandomDate = function(){
    var year = Math.round(Math.random() * 6) + 2015;
    var month = Math.round(Math.random() * 13) ;
    var day = Math.round(Math.random() * 32);
    return moment([year, month, day]);
}
```

Comment: Months are 0-11 here, and you should use `floor`, not `round`.  See [`Math.random` examples here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

Comment: Hi Matt. Would you happen to know how to filter the dates. My normal angular filters aren't working.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use .toDate()

```js
$scope.date = new moment().toDate()
```

Comment: This is great. But I still can't filter. Do you know why the filter doesn't work?http://jsfiddle.net/galnova/Pe2Zc/159/

Comment: Hey riotgear, I created an example, the filter is ok for me, try it http://jsfiddle.net/Pe2Zc/169

Answer (score 0):

You are already using moment. You can use angular-moment for date filters and much more. https://github.com/urish/angular-moment

Comment: I looked through this and added angular moment. Still the filter is not working. http://jsfiddle.net/galnova/Pe2Zc/164/